# Simple Flask application with debug set to True is not reloading in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

New to Docker, I have my Python/Flask service working `trial-api` but it does not reload the files when I change the code like it normally does (when not used through Docker.)

Meaning, I've got to delete the image and rebuild it all the time. What's the right way to do it?

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:

#############
## MARIADB ##
#############

    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./log/mariadb:/var/log/mysql:rw"
            - "./data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

################
## PHPMYADMIN ##
################

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        links:
            - mariadb:mysql
        environment:
            - "PMA_HOST=mysql"
            - "PMA_USER=root"
            - "PMA_PASSWORD=pass"
        ports:
            - "8001:80"

##############
## FRONTEND ##
##############

    frontend:
        image: skiychan/nginx-php7:latest
        volumes:
            - ./services/frontend/v1/src:/data/www
        links:
            - mariadb:mysql
        ports:
            - "80:80"

###############
## TRIAL API ##
###############

    trial-api:
        build: ./services/api/trial/
        volumes:
            - ./services/api/trial/src:/src
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
```

**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Buy groceries',
        'description': 'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Learners',
        'description': 'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/api/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, debug=True)
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-onbuild
ENTRYPOINT python ./src/app.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this line instead:

```
    - ./services/api/trial/src:/usr/src/app/src/
```